# Is every function in JS a closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I have been reading a fair bit about `closures` in JS.
I have been through various guides as this one https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-closures-simplified-d0d23fa06ba4

I still have one question though. Does a closure only refere to first order function (function returning a function). Or, is any function a `closure` ? 
The only difference I see really is like with some function not nested, one of the 3 scope chain (outer function's scope) would be empty still it doesn't exist.

Comment: We can say where ever we use the reference of the function to use the that function scope, we are using closure there.And to use the reference we either return object or another function from parent function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A closure is *created* by calling a function; the function itself isn't the closure. Conceptually, every function call implicitly causes a new closure to come into existence. For some functions, the closure is ephemeral and just vanishes as soon as the function returns:

```
function add2(n) {
  return n + 2;
}
```

That function returns only a number; nothing can refer to anything in the closure created by the function call, so the closure goes away and all you have left is the return value.

The closure becomes interesting when a function returns something that has one or more "hooks" into the local environment created when the function was called. (The function can expose the closure by modifying the global environment too.) So this function:

```
function addn(addend) {
  return function(n) {
    return n + addend;
  }
}
```

exposes the closure because the returned function has a reference to the parameter of the outer function.

I can't think of a way an ordinary function can expose a closure that doesn't *somehow* involve one or more functions that reference stuff from the local context (parameters, variables). (Generator functions are interesting, because `yield` kind-of always returns something that exposes the closure, I suppose.)

Comment: Note that in the first paragraph I wrote "Conceptually" — the runtime is free to optimize things if it figures out the closure can't be exposed.

Comment: And in the last paragraph, what I'm thinking about is a function that returns an object (or object structure) that involves just *references* to local variables etc; I can't think of a reason that that would require the closure itself to remain "alive".

Answer (score 1):

A closure is the **combination** of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared

for example,

```
 function greet(Say){
   return (
          function(name){
             console.log(Say + ' ' + name);
          }
   )
}
```

Now I'm I can do something like this,

```
greet('Hi')('Alex')
```

This line will return the string **'Hi Alex'**

Now I'm going to do something like this,

```
var sayGreet = greet('Hi');
```

If I console.log(sayGreet) it will be a function.

Now tell me where is this sayGreet variable defined? It is on the global level. Or in the other word global execution context.

Now let's do,

```
sayGreet('Alex')
```

inside this sayGreet function, we have a `console.log(Say + " " + name)` . We know `name` is Alex but what about `Say`? There is no sign of `Say` at this moment because the greet function already completed execution and returned a function.

Even though javascript still have the ability to refer to the Say value. Even it is completed the execution. This `Say` value can only be access by inner functions or nested functions.

This is call closure. A single function cannot be closure. There should be an outer lexical environment too.